# How to display manufacturer name in category.tpl?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to display some product info inside other views than Product, but I got problems.

I tried to add in my Category Controller file this code:

```
$this->data['manufacturer'] = $product['manufacturer'];
```

and add inside product array:

```
'manufacturer'    => $result['manufacturer'],
```

and in my Category.tpl View file:

```
<?php if ($manufacturer) { ?>
   <span><?php echo $manufacturer; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

I got no errors but the  tag comes empty. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: What is that You want to achieve? Do You want to display manufacturer for each product listed in category?

Comment: hi @shadyyx, yes. I just want to display the manufacturer name along with the info that already exist for each product in category list.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this to the `$this->data['products']` array along with all the other info that is made available to the `category.tpl` file as you rightly pointed out. The `$this->data['manufacturer'] ...` is not needed and is going to show nothing. Rather than give you the answer on a plate, take a look at the `rating` values in the controller and view files to see how they're assigned and used and try and duplicate that

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

In `catalog/controller/product/category.php` find this line:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
```

(should be line 238 for OC 1.5.6) -> here the products are processed and assigned to the template variable. In this array, add a new index after e.g. *rating*:

```
'rating' => $result['rating'],
'manufacturer' => $result['manufacturer'], // <= YOUR NEW LINE
```

Because this controller uses method `ModelCatalogProduct::getProducts()` and this method does not populate manufacturer information, You would need also to modify the `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` and add

```
m.name as manufacturer
```

into the `SELECT` part of the query (add `,` after if it is not the last entry of `SELECT` clause) and then add

```
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id";
```

**after** this line:

```
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";
```

Now in Your template for category product listing You may use

```
<?php echo $product['manufacturer']; ?>
```

inside the `foreach($products as $product)` loop. Little more edits and not as straight forward. Better if You just could do these edits via a vQmod file...

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not late. just send array of manufacturer in product array by

```
'manufacturer' => $result['manufacturer']
```

In `category.tpl` file echo inside loop

```
<div class="manufacturer"><?php if($product['manufacturer']){
            echo ($product['manufacturer']);
        }?>
</div>
```

It still doesn't appear in front but you can see data by viewing source code.

Because Opencart Uses the script function `function Display()` to display product (view & list)

(see code inside script tag, after content_bottom div)

It overrides the display class (product-list and product-grid)
so add this in script

```
var manufacturer= $(element).find('.manufacturer').html();

if (manufacturer != null) {
    html += '<div class="rating">' + manufacturer + '</div>';
}
```

Keep the code in both if and else condition so that manufacturer will appear on both List and grid view.
Hope this helps